# Maven compile produces multiple versions of the same class in target?

Tags: java, compilation, maven-3

I have a project with many different dependencies. When I run

```
mvn clean compile
```

For some calsses I get multiple versions of the same class, example

```
./classes/com/.../MyClass$1$1.class
./classes/com/.../MyClass$1$10.class
./classes/com/.../MyClass$1$11.class
./classes/com/.../MyClass$1$12.class
./classes/com/.../MyClass$1$13.class
./classes/com/.../MyClass$1$14.class
```

etc.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Are those just inner classes? Can you post MyClass.java.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `$1` notation is for anonymous inner classes. Running `javac` will result in the same sort of output.

Comment: You are correct. It's a mapper class that does callbacks via a direct interface implementation! I almost didn't catch it. Thanks!